# Does SAML make sense for a windows authentication on premise desktop application?

Tags: saml

Recently we were asked if our product supports SAML.  Our application is a Windows thick client application written in .net that connects directly to SQL server, and we use windows authentication in the connection string so that users don't have to enter their user name and password.  Would implementing SAML solve anything at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You mean SAML as a client?

If you had SAML you could connect to a company's IDP (like ADFS) and they could authenticate on their repository and still use your product.

Comment: Well our app is an intranet app installed inside their network using their SQL server, from our point of view SAML doesn't look like it would solve anything.